# How to resolve disagreement with project teammates over which professor to work with?

Tags: masters, professorship, coursework, collaboration, interpersonal-issues

I would like some advice about a conflict I am having in a graduate course taught by two professors. I am pursuing a masters (MS) degree in Finance and for the capstone course in the program, each group (3-4) students is required to complete an individual research project.

The professors responsible for the course both have PhDs in Finance but in slightly different research areas. My team-mates both insist that we only work with the professor who is more specialized/knowledgeable in our area.

As the course is taught by both professors  equally, I feel it is important to keep both professors abreast of our progress. I feel fairly confident that both have equal weight in evaluating us and I don't want to slight either. How should I explain this fact to my team members as I am the leader of our team?

For additional background, my team members are all from China whose academic culture is wholly different from Western standards.

Comment: Ask the two professors what they want you to do.

Comment: @mkennedy I don't thats a viable option. Naturally both professors will probably say to work with them both. Also simply by asking can be considered a slight as it implies a disrespect of their academic knowledge and status

Comment: _Naturally both professors will probably say to work with them both_ — So then you have your answer. Why is that unrealistic?

Comment: _Also simply asking can be a slight_ — [citation needed] — _as it implies a disrespect of their academic knowledge and starus_ — [citation needed]

Comment: Faculty want to help you, @Anthony, it's their job.

Comment: @mkennedy Can you please turn your comment into a (slightly expanded) answer, so that I can vote for it?

Answer (score 1):

To expand the comments above into an answer: ask the professors what they think is a good idea, ideally both at the same time (e.g., at the end of a class where they are both there).  You have less chance of coming off as disrespectful, since you approach from the perspective of a student desiring guidance.  If they say you should work with both, then that's probably a fine plan to follow as well.